# getting error while eager loading

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am eager loading gallery like this this

```
$user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
        $favorites = Favorite::with('gallery')->where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
        dd($favorites->gallery);
```

and getting this error message:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$gallery
```

My Favorite class looks like this:

```
class Favorite extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'favorites';
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
    public function gallery(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Gallery::class, 'gallery_id');
    }
}
```

however if I do this

```
$user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
        $favorites = Favorite::with('gallery')->where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
        dd($favorites);
```

then I get this [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$favorites` is a collection and you can't get property of a collection.

You need to use `first()` to get first object from a collection:

```
$favorites = Favorite::with('gallery')->where('user_id', $user->id)->first();
```

Or to iterate over collection and get all objects:

```
foreach ($favorites as $favorite) {
    echo $favorite->gallery;
}
```